# Unable to execute binary file. Exec format error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, 64-bit, 32-bit, node.js

I recently heard about [Breach](http://breach.cc/), a Node.js based browser. I was following the instructions from [here](http://codeforgeek.com/2014/08/download-install-breach-browser-ubuntu-14-04/) to install it but got the following error :

**breach-v0.3.22-alpha.6-linux-x64/__AUTO_UPDATE_BUNDLE__/exo_browser/exo_browser: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error**

After some googling, I found that it is because I am trying to install the 64 bit package on the 32 bit Ubuntu installation. I tried to find 32 bit package of the same but ended up with no luck. The browser is only available in 64 bit packet(as far as i know).

So, My question is :

Is it possible to somehow install it on the 32 bit OS or if any program available which can run 64 bit applications on the 32 bit OS.

I have been googling around and found no help. Can anyone help me?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 (32 Bit).

Answer (score 2):

If you have a 32-bit OS, then you need to have 32-bit applications.  The only way to get 64-bit applications to run is to run them under a 64-bit OS.  BTW, it is possible to run 32-bit applications under a 64-bit OS.

So the suggestion here:

1. Find and use the 32-bit package
2. Find the source, do a full recompilation for a 32-bit system, install and use that.
3. Upgrade your system to a 64-bit Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the 32-bit package is not yet available.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run 64-bit executables on a 32-bit kernel:

[Can I run 64-bit executables on a 32-bit Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/111975/can-i-run-64-bit-executables-on-a-32-bit-linux)

A poster on that thread suggested using an emulator (i.e. emulating a 32-bit architecture).

This may sound a bit unhelpful, but it's usually best to go with a 64-bit install unless you have a specific need for 32 (i.e. hardware-related) as it's easier to run 32-bit software on a 64-bit kernel.